# Automated Object Creation, How to Control/Increment Names?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, constructor

I've hit a bit of a hurdle with creating objects using user input for variables. Basically the program determines what type of object the user wants, creates it, and then asks if the user wants to add another object. In this example the object is a manager, which is a subclass of employee.

```
void add_manager()
{
    string name;
    //Performs a bunch of checks to ensure the input is valid.
    name = get_string_input("Please input the name of the employee.");
    //Creates a manager object.
    manager manager1(name);
    //Goes back to previous function, restarts process of finding out employee type.
    ask_employee();
}
```

I will be storing pointers to each object in a dynamic array elsewhere. The point of the array is just to get values out of each object to use in some printouts, so I was expecting to just loop over the array, get the value of each, and print. (Rough example)

The part I'm not sure about is how to change the object constructor call so the objects are made as manager1, manager2 etc. There will be a varied number made due to what the user wants, and I was hoping to keep them in a way to tell the difference.

Since I will be accessing the objects via pointers, do the object names even need to be different? Or can objects and pointers all have the same name?

Comment: Unless you traverse your array trying to find a `manager` by `name`, nothing really cares about it.

Comment: Well there's more values stored inside each object than just a name, it just happens that the manager constructor only requires that one.

Comment: At the moment the `manager1` object will be destroyed at the end of the `add_manager` function because it is allocated on the stack,  I am guessing that is not what you want?  Perhaps you want to allocate dynamically on the heap instead?

Comment: It should be destroyed when the entire program ends shouldn't it? The code I put above is only a snippet of the relevant part. Everything else I left out, but there is an automatic display of a bunch of information regarding managers, and other employees before the end of the program, at which point I want it all to be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the object names even need to be different?

They don't need to be different, when you store them in the array there is no connection between the objects and their names, e.g. they can be all instantiated using `manager1`<sup>1</sup>. (Additionally, you can't use their name for search.)

What differentiates the objects are the values of their data members. Thus, if you want to search the objects define an object `id` or `name` as data member and then you can use it in your search criterion to find a particular `manager`.

### Edit 1:

One way to create an object counter is by defining a data member:
`static int counter = 0;`. Then you increment your `counter` in the constructor to reflect object instantiation and decrement it in the destructor.

### Edit 2:

If you want to store objects it would be better to use `vector<object_type> container_name` (instead of arrays). To do this you need to define a vector outside the object you want to store. In case of storing pointers to type `object_type`, you can do something like:

```
vector<object_type*> container_name;

object_type* ObjectInstance = new object_type(parameters);

// store in vector
container_name.emplace_back(ObjectInstance);
```

---

<sup>1.The names you give variables are available to the program only at compile time, when you turn it from source into an executable file. Afterwards, when you want to create objects , those kinds of information are no longer available. The program only knows about the machine addresses where operands to machine instructions are located.</sup>

Comment: Someone did suggest me having a static counter within the manager class to enable searching, but I wasn't sure how to make that work. As for the main point though, so even though every manager object is created with manager manager1, since the pointer created will point to it's specific manager object, it makes no difference? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

Since managers objects can be in an infinite number, you can't name them all. C++ is a statically typed language. You strictly need to keep your manager objects in an array-like structure:

```
std::vector<manager *> vManagers;

void add_manager()
{
    string name;
    //Performs a bunch of checks to ensure the input is valid.
    name = get_string_input("Please input the name of the employee.");
    //Creates a manager object.
    vManagers.push_back(new manager(name));
    //Goes back to previous function, restarts process of finding out employee type.
    while(ask_employee()
    {
        name = get_string_input("Please input the name of the employee.");
        vManagers.push_back(new manager(name));
    }
}
```

So that when you need manager object you can call:

```
 vManagers[n]->GetData();
```

But note that you need to delete manager object pointers in apppriate places to avoid leaks:

```
delete vManagers[n];
vManagers[n] = NULL;
```

Comment: Wouldn't keep pointers to them in an array for the life of the program do the same thing? We haven't been shown vectors, and we need to use dynamic memory somewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to get this vector system to work, but I think because I have the vector stored inside another object I'm doing it wrong. I've made a post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316072/vector-array-inside-object-holding-objects-of-another-class going into more detail if you're able to have a look, since you have a better idea of what I need.