# Vector/Array inside Object, Holding Objects of Another Class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, vector

I am trying to store either the objects of a base class (`employee`), or pointers to the objects inside a vector/array in another class (`finance`) object. The number of employee objects depends on the user, so it needs to work dynamically. So far I have this:

`finance.h`

```
#ifndef FINANCE
#define FINANCE
#include "freight.h"

class finance
{
public:
    finance();
    ~finance();
};

#endif // FINANCE
```

`finance.cpp`

```
#include "finance.h"
using namespace std;

finance::finance()
{
    vector<employee *> vemployee; //first problem line
}

finance::~finance()
{

}
```

`main.cpp`

```
void add_manager()
{
    string name;
    name = get_string_input("Please input the name of the employee.");
    vManagers.push_back(new manager(name)); //second problem line
    ask_employee();
}
```

`Main.cpp` also has includes on all my `.h` files as well as `finance.cpp`. I am getting errors on both main and `finance.cpp` saying about expected primary expressions and not declared in scope.

### Note:

I'm clearly doing something wrong but I honestly have no idea as vectors is something I haven't been taught yet. If there's a way to do it with arrays I don't mind trying that either.

Comment: Do classes `employee` and `manager` even exist?

Comment: They do, but I figured it was better to only post the one that have direct interaction with the vector, rather than post 200+ lines of code. The classes work fine, it only broke when I tried adding in the storage of objects inside Finance.

Comment: Well, you should not post 200+ lines of code either. You are supposed to reduce your code to the minimum number of lines necessary to reproduce the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well that's what I've done here isn't it? The add manager function tries to add an object to the array inside finance. What could I cut out, or add aside from the three parts I included?

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. It misses the *complete* requirement of the MCVE rule.  `4:21: fatal error: freight.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: It would only compile if I added the add_employee function, which includes all the other add functions, all of which use a bunch of functions to check if user input is within the requirements. This also requires all of the header and .cpp files to be posted. I can either try and post what's relevant to the actual problem, or I can post the entire 200+ lines.

Comment: Nonsense. Alternatives are clearly explained in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I doubt that each and every of those 200+ lines is required to reproduce the problem. You should delete those lines which do not change anything about your problem. If you give us either 200+ lines of code *or* an incomplete code example, then you will not get high-quality answers, because nobody wants to wade through hundreds of lines of code or make random guesses about the problem.

Comment: I'd like to add that the ability of reducing programming problems in this way is an essential skill in software engineering and one that really pays of. Nobody is born with it, but we all eventually learnt it over the years. Train it! :)

Comment: Well the whole question was whether I had the vector lines in the right place or not, which as the answer below says, I did not. Since I'm still having problems I will likely make a new question showing more code. Though I still doubt I'll get it below 150 even with deleting things.

Comment: I realise that reducing code is a big deal. The whole reason why I can't show a small portion that compiles is because of that. So many of the functions overlap and interact that they all need each other in order to compile. >_<

Comment: Just going to add one last comment to this since I don't know if you're still around, but I just trimmed it down as much as I can for it to still compile (aside from the vector issue), and it's still at 223 lines after altering it to not need other classes in the hierarchy. This doesn't include comments or my noncode questions. Not sure what else I can do to keep within the guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to keep *vManagers* in class declaration:

```
//finance.h file
#ifndef FINANCE
#define FINANCE
#include "freight.h" //assuming you have defined manager class here

class finance
{
    public:
        finance();
        ~finance();
        void add_manager();
    private:
        vector<manager*> vManagers;
};

#endif // FINANCE
//finance.cpp file

#include "finance.h"
using namespace std;

finance::finance()
{

}

finance::~finance()
{
    for(int i=0; i< vManagers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vManagers[i] != NULL)
        {
            delete vManagers[i];
        }
    }
}

finance::add_manager()
{
    string name;
    name = get_string_input("Please input the name of the employee.");
    vManagers.push_back(new manager(name)); //second problem line
    while(ask_employee()
    {
       name = get_string_input("Please input the name of the employee.");
       vManagers.push_back(new manager(name)); //second problem line
    }
}
```

now you can create and use finance object in main.cpp

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I'm not sure if the while loop approach will work as manager is a subclass of employee, with two other subclasses existing. I've changed it so that the vector is of employee type and is called Employees. Can I have the same format in main in the OP, and just change the type of object being made/added?

Comment: yes, you can use employee instead of manager but if manager is an employee type and you have other employee types, you can just use an enumerate member for employee type, and you do not have to define a new class for all employee subclasses.

Comment: Still throwing a heap of errors. Seems to have a problem with the vector being of type employee. As mentioned above in the comments I can't really paste the entire code, but thanks for helping in any case.